# Isn't it time to migrate all Mathematica questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

Now that https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ is live, let these archived questions go to their proper home.

Comment: You must really hate Mathematica, as you don't even have an account on that site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Old questions are not migrated to new sites.

The idea is to let the community define itself and its own standards through *new* questions. Migrating old questions isn't fair, and serves very little purpose.

You might be interested in this recent blog post: [Respect the community – your own, and others’](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)

Comment: But it does serve a purpose: people searching the archives will find answers. What if we asked on their meta if they wanted the questions migrated? If both parties accept, what is the problem?

Comment: There are two purposes to migration: 1) because the question is off-topic for the site on which it is asked, and 2) because the question is likely to get a better answer on the target site. Neither of those apply for the old Mathematica questions on Stack Overflow. Additionally, like I said, we have a policy against forcing old questions on new communities. We encourage the new communities to define themselves with *their own* questions, not our old crap. @emre

Comment: @Emre: What archives?

Comment: Those are valid reasons to migrate, but not the only ones; I have given another IMO. I do not regard archived questions as "crap". On the contrary, I want them migrated *because* they are valuable. Moreover they are more valuable there than here because these questions are more likely to be sought and referenced there. *** @BoltClock: I mean all questions with a Mathematica tag. We could distinguish between closed/open/old questions but that's something to debate after deciding to migrate at all.

Comment: @Emre Since Mathematica is not off-topic on SO, and the questions asked there is valid, why would we need to migrate those questions. Specialized SE sites exists for users that work on only one specific technology, and if they don't, they are more then free to ask on SO. Just because a SE site exists for a topic, doesn't mean that topic has become off topic for SO and everything needs to be migrated. This has never been done for any of the sites, so why must we do it now?